# Firebase Database Rest API: Returns incorrect results when all nodes contain the same value except one

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Json data that is sorted by highest viewed by using

`OrderBy("Views").LimitToLast(10)`

All elements have the same (Views) value except one.

This is the Full Json data Without adding a specific limit:

https://ameen-66522.firebaseio.com/Main/News/Categories/Education/.json?print=pretty&orderBy=%22Views%22

```
{
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01dxifhtpEn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01iddfh2tpEn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01idsdfh2tpEn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01idsdfhtpEn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01idxfh2tpEn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifddhtpEn" : {
    "Views" : 50
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifdshtpEn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh21tpEn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh2dstpEn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh2tpEdsn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh2tpEn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh2txpEn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifhds2tpEn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifhewtpEn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifhtdxpEn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  }
}
```

When I use

`OrderBy("Views").LimitToLast(10)`

It will fetch the top 10 elements correctly and the Last Id will be

`-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifddhtpEn`

**It is the one that has a different value from the rest of the data**

Here the Response result :

https://ameen-66522.firebaseio.com/Main/News/Categories/Education/.json?print=pretty&orderBy=%22Views%22&limitToLast=10

Now it is supposed that when I fetch the remaining data starting from the
**lastId**

`-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifddhtpEn`

and

**LastValue**

`50`

It will return the remaining data correctly even in fact it will return data that was fetched in the first 10 and this problem occurs when all the data carry the same value of views except for only one different.

https://ameen-66522.firebaseio.com/Main/News/Categories/Education/.json?print=pretty&orderBy=%22Views%22&limitToLast=11&endAt=50,%22-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifddhtpEn%22

```
{
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01idxfh2tpEn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifddhtpEn" : {
    "Views" : 50
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifdshtpEn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh21tpEn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh2dstpEn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh2tpEdsn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh2tpEn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh2txpEn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifhds2tpEn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifhewtpEn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifhtdxpEn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  }
}
```

##### it is supposed to return :

```
{
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01dxifhtpEn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01iddfh2tpEn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01idsdfh2tpEn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01idsdfhtpEn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01idxfh2tpEn" : {
    "Views" : 20
  },
  "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifddhtpEn" : {
    "Views" : 50
  }
```

Thanks for the help :) I appreciate your work

Comment: Show code no output.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I fetch the data exactly as shown in the link, and then I process it and display it inside the application using c#

Comment: @Mises: The https://ameen-66522.firebaseio.com/Main/News/Categories/Education/.json?print=pretty&orderBy=%22Views%22&limitToLast=11&endAt=50,%22-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifddhtpEn%22 is the API call here.

Comment: @OLIVER I think Frank was trying target you not me in his question.

Comment: Yes of course This link is the database I'm working on at the moment

Comment: Uhm, I actually was targeting you @Mises, since you asked for code. In this question, the https://ameen-66522.firebaseio.com/Main/News/Categories/Education/.json?print=pretty&orderBy=%22Views%22&limitToLast=11&endAt=50,%22-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifddhtpEn%22 URL *is* the equivalent of code. It's the REST API of the database being accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this node is the last one in your JSON when you order by view count:

```
"-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifddhtpEn" : {
  "Text" : 6,
  "Title" : "some title",
  "Views" : 50
},
```

So when you do this query: [orderBy="Views"&limitToLast=10](https://ameen-66522.firebaseio.com/Main/News/Categories/Education/.json?print=pretty&orderBy=%22Views%22&limitToLast=10), you're asking for the last 10 nodes when ordered by `Views` count.

You then use the key of the **last** node in your next query: [orderBy="Views"&limitToLast=11&endAt=50,"-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifddhtpEn"](https://ameen-66522.firebaseio.com/Main/News/Categories/Education/.json?print=pretty&orderBy=%22Views%22&limitToLast=11&endAt=50,%22-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifddhtpEn%22), so now you're asking for the last 11 nodes ending at the last node already. That `endAt` clause is superfluous as far as I can see, to this is the same as [orderBy="Views"&limitToLast=11](https://ameen-66522.firebaseio.com/Main/News/Categories/Education/.json?print=pretty&orderBy=%22Views%22&limitToLast=11).

The thing to keep in mind here is that you're paginating backwards from the end of your data set. So to get the second page from the bottom, you need to know the Views+key of the **first** item on the last page.

Comment: Do you mean that I have to fetch 11 node in the beginning and consider the first key as the last id, So I have to start from `-Mn7-ZxkUPO01idxfh2tpEn` and `20` to show the new data

Comment: Say you have 30 nodes (let's call them nodes 1-30), so 3 pages of 10 nodes. Page 3 (which you seem to want firsts) will be `limitToLast(10)` without any `endAt`. Page 2 is then `limitToLast(11)` with `endAt(value+key of node 21)`. Or even (just found out this operation is also in the rest API: `endBefore(value+key of node 21)` with `limitToLast(10)`.

Comment: Thank you for all your help with my many important questions  Best regards

Comment: Happy to help. If you bump into more problems, please can you generate a new dataset for them through, with: 1) more easily identifiable unique keys? 2) more unique values? 3) no more properties than strictly necessary? That'll make it a lot faster to help you, and easier for others to either help, or understand what's going on (which makes it more useful in this knowledge base we're all building here).

Comment: Sorry about the messy keys and unimportant properties  Thank you for your patience,But let me ask you about your comment that you said you have to fetch the first 10 first, but how will I know the key for the next page,Or is it supposed to fetch the first 11 and store the first key as the key for the next page

Comment: Please be very explicit on what you mean here, as "first" and "next" are really hard to coordinate when we're talking about paginating backwards. That's why I indicated node numbers in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70174465/firebase-database-rest-api-returns-incorrect-results-when-all-nodes-contain-the/70177372?noredirect=1#comment124055528_70177372).

Comment: Please, how can I find the **ID** and the **Value** of the first item on the last page? Because this data you see is not static I mean when I publish an application I will add many nodes using push keys generated by the firebase database,So I am looking for a way to fetch the first 10  using `orderBy="Views"&limitToLast=10` and Save a Specific Key **ID and his value** So I can fetch the other 10 data starting from **that id and value**

Comment: We discussed this before, didn't we? When you get the results for that last page from the REST API you have to re-sort it in your application code on Views and then on key. The first node in those sorted results, is then the anchor node for the page before the current one.

Comment: In that fiddle: `var sorted = full.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.Views);` missed the fact that for nodes with the same `Views` value, you need to order them on their key.